# How do i limit the array to store only 3 objects in it?

Tags: javascript

### counter variable

```
 let counter = 2;
```

### carousel object

```
let carousel = {
    "carousel": {
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "cards": []
    }
}
```

### card object

```
  let card = {
      "card": {
          "title": "Please select the market areas ",
          "description": "",
           "links": []
      }
  }
```

### link object

```
  let link = {
    "type": "post_message",
    "title": " ",
    "value": " "
  }
```

i need to store 3 link object inside a card object, should create a new card object if there are more than 3 link objects

below is the function what i have written

```
    for (let i = 0; i < functional_categories_links.length; i++) {
        if (card.card.links.length <= counter) {
            card.card.links.push(link.value = functional_categories_links[i]);
        } else {
            //card.card.links.push(link.value = functional_categories_links[i]);
            carousel.carousel.cards.push(card);
            card.card.links.push(link.value = functional_categories_links[i])
            counter += counter;
        }
    }
 return carousel;
 };
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have so far? Are you seeing any errors? Or seeing unexpected results?

Comment: I'm seeing unexpected results

Comment: @DBS My guess is that he doesn't clear / reset the `card` object and therefor runs into pushing it continuesly

Comment: @VijayRajagopal you have  card.card.links.push in both the if and else, remove it from the else.

Comment: even removing that doesn't make any success.

Comment: 3 objects should be the output, but then it shows 4 instead.

Comment: You can create a cards template object (an empty one). Then create a copy, something like: `const template = //your cards object` and then `let card = Object.assign(template);`. Then after you have pushed 3 links, push `card` to your `carousel` and use `card = Object.assign(template);` again to reset it.

Comment: Or you simply use `card.card.links = []`. I just like making it difficult, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the approach of deep copy, since whatever has been done by you was approximately* right but due to shallow copy it might updating the same object.

```
let functional_categories_links = [{type:"A"},{type:"B"},{type:"C"},{type:"D"},{type:"E"}];
let carousel={carousel : {cards : []}};
let card = {card : {links : []}}; 
let cardCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(card)); //Making Deep Copy
for(let i=0;i<functional_categories_links.length;i++){ //Iterating through the links
if(cardCopy.card.links.length<3){
   cardCopy.card.links.push(functional_categories_links[i]);
}
else{
   carousel.carousel.cards.push(cardCopy); //When size limit exceeded - then pushing into array
   cardCopy=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(card));
   i--;
}
}
if(cardCopy.card.links.length!=0){
     carousel.carousel.cards.push(cardCopy);
}
```

What I did, followed the approximately the same approach, I have initialised the deep copy of the "card" object and whenever the limit is crossing (i.e you want to store 3 links in one card and then in new one) creating again the deep copy of the card.

Note (Just thought to share) - **I was trying with spread operator(I thought spread operator does deep copy of the properties), Now came to know spread operator *exactly* doesn't deep copy the properties.**

[image]

Hope you need something like.

Comment: there might be other solutions possible, I followed the simple approach of deep copying the properties of the object